# Убрать корзину в дочерней теме Storefront

Tags: wordpress

В шаблоне Storefront регистрируется action

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
```

Подскажите, как ее удалить в дочерней теме.

Пробовал так:

```
remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
```

и так:

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'remove_storefront_header_cart', 60 );
function remove_storefront_header_cart() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
}
```

У меня не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вывод всего, что связано с корзиной, сохраняется WooCommerce в cookie, поэтому для того, чтобы увидеть изменения, надо очистить cookie.

Функции дочерней темы вызываются до функций основной, поэтому просто  `remove_action()` не работает - на данный момент в глобальном массиве хуков WordPress нет такой акции.

Второй способ правильный, только в нем надо в первой строке заменить 60 на 30, скажем. Тогда при вызове `do_action('storefront_header'...)` сначала будет выполнена функция `remove_storefront_header_cart()`, поскольку у нее приоритет 30, и она удалит стандартную функцию с приоритетом 60.

Если же в первой строке 60, то ваша функция `remove_storefront_header_cart()` будет записана в глобальном массиве хуков ПОСЛЕ стандартной. Так уж там устроено - первая регистрируемая акция выполняется последней среди акций с одинаковым приоритетом.

В общем, попробуйте такой код:

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'remove_storefront_header_cart', 30 );
function remove_storefront_header_cart() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
}
```

Comment: В родительской удаляется первым способом без очистки куки

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы убрать корзину, переместить заголовок продукта и т.п., использую [хук-событие `init`](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/init):

> Событие срабатывает после того, как WordPress полностью загружен, но до того, как любые header заголовки были отправлены.
>
> К моменту срабатывания init <...> функции темы уже подключены и все установки установлены: размеры картинок миниатюр, поддержка меню и т.д.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_storefront' );
function custom_storefront() {
  remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
}
```

Код работает и для дочерней темы Storefront, и для плагина [Theme Customisations](https://github.com/woocommerce/theme-customisations).